# Calculate value difference between two different CSV files python

Tags: python, csv

I have two differenct csv files:

> outputnovember.csv

```
symbol,name,amount
A,john,2
D,mary,6
E,bob,9
m,liz,-8
p,peter,-2
```

A total 2,Positive total 17,Negative total -10

> outputdecember.csv

```
symbol,name,amount
A,john,2
D,mary,26
m,liz,-1
p,peter,-2
```

A total 2,Positive total 26,Negative total -3

how do i calculate the difference between the calculated values of the two file so that the following is appended to outdecember: A total 0, Posiitve total 9, Negative total-17

here's my code so far:

```
import csv

f=open('outputnovember.csv')
csv_f= csv.reader(f)

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f_input, open('outdecember.csv', 'w') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    header = next(csv_input)
    csv_output.writerow(header)

    sum_positive = sum_negative = sum_a = 0

    for cols in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
        value = int(cols[2])

        if cols[0] == 'A':
            sum_a += value
        if value >= 0:
            sum_positive += value
        else:
            sum_negative += value


        csv_output.writerow(["A total {}".format(sum_a)],
        csv_output.writerow(["Positive total {}".format(sum_positive)]) 
        csv_output.writerow(["Negative total {}".format(sum_negative)])
```

... here is where i'm stuck to retrieve the values from outputnovember.csv and find the difference from outputdecember.csv

Thanks all
B

Comment: how do you want to append it? as columns or at the bottom?

Comment: append to the bottom.